# Laravel's AsgardCMS doesn't work on Ubuntu properly

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, laravel-5, asgardcms

I have an installation of AsgardCMS on a git repo. While it seems to work fine on Windows (7 Professional) and MacOS operating systems, I am having trouble running it on my Ubuntu OS (16.04 LTS).
Particularly, `http://localhost/cms/public` works on Windows and MacOS but the same invokes a 404 on Ubuntu. Please note that,`http://localhost/cms/public/index.php` again works fine on Ubuntu, but I need standardised URLs on all platforms.
I tried setting this in my `httpd.conf` file, to redirect requests to index.php if a directory is requested:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
```

But I can't say it helped.

We are actually a team of devs who work on different dev environments.
Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: probably the document root in your virtual host is not configured properly. This seems to be Apache configuration. Would you share your Virtual Host config?

Comment: Hi @MinaAbadir, I got it fixed long ago. It was indeed some hosts config. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically, the `mod_rewrite` module in `httpd.conf`needed to be uncommented. And `AllowOverride All` in the same file.